# Why upgrading to Windows 10 anniversity edition fails

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1607

After running upgrade Windows 10 to anniversity edition screen in blank.
After computer restart windows 10 restores its previous version.
Tried two times but problem persists.

How to upgrade ?
Earlier Windows 10 works OK, all windows 10 uodates are installed.

C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setuperr.log contains:

```
2016-08-06 11:20:32, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionImpl<class CDlpErrorImpl<class CDlpObjectInternalImpl<class CUnknownImpl<class IMoSetupDlpAction> > > >::Suspend(1066): Result = 0xC1800104
2016-08-06 11:20:32, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteInstallMode(735): Result = 0x800705BB
2016-08-06 11:20:32, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteDownlevelMode(391): Result = 0x800705BB
2016-08-06 11:20:32, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::Execute(236): Result = 0x800705BB
2016-08-06 11:20:32, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupHost::Execute(372): Result = 0x800705BB
2016-08-06 11:30:37, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2016-08-06 11:30:43, Error                 SP     pSPRemoveUpgradeRegTree: failed to delete reg tree HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade[gle=0x00000005]
2016-08-06 11:30:54, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2016-08-06 11:30:57, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: "id" attribute is mandatory. void __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::LoadSupportedComponent(class UnBCL::XmlNode *,int,class Mig::CMXEMigrationXml *,class Mig::CMXEXmlComponent *)
2016-08-06 11:31:14, Error                 CSI    00000001 (F) 80220008 [Error,Facility=FACILITY_STATE_MANAGEMENT,Code=8] #90960# from CWcmScalarInstanceCore::GetCurrentValue(options = 393216 (0x00060000), status = [6]"(null)", value = { type: 40972 (0x0000a00c), bytes ( 12 (0x0000000c) ): 65006e002d00550053000000 })
[gle=0x80004005]
2016-08-06 11:31:17, Error                 CSI    00000002 (F) 80220008 [Error,Facility=FACILITY_STATE_MANAGEMENT,Code=8] #162347# from CWcmScalarInstanceCore::GetCurrentValue(options = 393216 (0x00060000), status = [6]"(null)", value = { type: 40972 (0x0000a00c), bytes ( 12 (0x0000000c) ): 650074002d00450045000000 })
[gle=0x80004005]
2016-08-06 11:31:51, Error      [0x080389] MIG    Failure while calling IDiscovery->Gather for Plugin={ServerPath="Microsoft-Windows-AppX-Deployment-Server\AppxUpgradeMigrationPlugin.dll", CLSID={AE27C1A6-25F2-45FD-9A28-081B81F29E0A}, ThreadingModel=Apartment}. Error: 0x80010105
2016-08-06 11:31:51, Error                 SP     Error READ, 0x80010105 while gathering/applying object: pre-scan, Action,CMXEPlugin,C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests,Microsoft-Windows-AppX-Deployment-Server\AppxUpgradeMigrationPlugin.dll,{AE27C1A6-25F2-45FD-9A28-081B81F29E0A},Apartment. Will return 2[gle=0x000000cb]
2016-08-06 11:31:54, Error                 CSI    00000003 (F) 80220008 [Error,Facility=FACILITY_STATE_MANAGEMENT,Code=8] #251064# from CWcmScalarInstanceCore::GetCurrentValue(options = 393216 (0x00060000), status = [6]"(null)", value = { type: 40972 (0x0000a00c), bytes ( 12 (0x0000000c) ): 650074002d00450045000000 })
[gle=0x80004005]
2016-08-06 11:32:02, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2016-08-06 11:32:07, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: Component with display name: Plugin/{C939EC0F-2F56-4CE8-AF56-2336596A5FA7} already loaded __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::CMXEMigrationXml(class Mig::CPlatform *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::XmlDocument *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::String *)
2016-08-06 11:34:54, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ff9c714f-b864-4f43-ae39-ec07d7385abe}: Skipping device 'USB\VID_X00X&PID_Y00Y\695CF69C264A49E800001' without driver.
2016-08-06 11:34:54, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ff9c714f-b864-4f43-ae39-ec07d7385abe}: Skipping device 'USB\VID_X00X&PID_Y00Y\695CF69C264A49E800002' without driver.
2016-08-06 11:35:03, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {526D451C-721A-4b97-AD34-DCE5D8CD22C5}: [shmig] Failed to get preferred homegroup with hr=0x80070490
2016-08-06 11:36:23, Error                        CSetupAutomation::Resurrect: File not found: C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\automation.dat[gle=0x00000002]
2016-08-06 11:36:23, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::ResurrectAutomation: Failed to resurrect automation: 0x80070002[gle=0x00000002]
2016-08-06 11:36:23, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
```

This is Dell Precision M6600 
ATI video driver is disabled in device manager (video card does not work stopped working) and external monitor with Dell builtin Intel HD graphics  is used.
Not sure is this related to this issue.

**update**

After running setup.exe from usb stick previous version is still resotered. However in this case the following message appears on startup:

[image]

This is posted here also:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/error-when-upgrading-to-windows-10-0xc1900101/0e1c698a-6ea2-4bf0-aad4-0a26604f3200

Comment: Try using the [media creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10/) to create a USB stick, then do the upgrade from setup.exe on the USB stick. If this fails, it will give a proper error message which will be more useful to understanding the problem.

Comment: You have a permission problem.  Have you used any "anti-spying" tools on this installation by chance?

Comment: @Ramhound. I dont know which are anti-spying tools. So  those are probably not used. Visual Studion Community Edition is installed and Windows error dump file creation is turned on. Hyper-V is installed.

Comment: Have you tried mounting an .ISO and upgrading that way?

Comment: @Ramhound. I created USB stick using media creation tool from Michael Hampon comment, booted Dell Precision from it and selected upgrade. `The computer is started using the Windows installation media ...` message appers and upgrade is not preformed. It asks to start windows in regular way and run setup.exe from Windows.

Comment: @Andrus - You are not doing what was suggested.  You need to launch the setup.exe from within Windows.  **You cannot upgrade to Version 1607 by booting to the installation disk.**

Comment: @Ramhound I ran now setup.exe from usb stick. I updated question and provided message which appears after windows retored previous version. How to fix this ?

Comment: Like I said.  You have a permissions problem.  The `setuperr.log` you provided indicates which folders have the wrong permission.  [The new error seems to be connected to a display driver.  Since you have an older GPU it might be connected.](http://www.tenforums.com/installation-setup/2126-windows-10-error-code-0xc1900101-0x30018-4.html).  Try without either display driver being installed.

Comment: ATI Radeon GPU card is not working. ATI video driver is disabled in device manager. If this driver is enabled, blank screen appears in old windows 10 also. Maybe Anniversity Edition turns it on? How to try without display driver ? How to fix folder permissions ?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I created USB stick and ran setup.exe from it. I updated question with error message. How to fix this ?